# can this css gallery layout be done?

Tags: css, flexbox, gallery

I've tried using flex and grid, but can't meet all the requirements. Was beginning to think it can't be done.  I had thought you didn't need media queries, but maybe you have too?

[image]

Comment: it can be done very easily by using flexbox or grid. please write down some of your code.

Comment: This feels like you just posted your homework ...

Comment: Thanks, still working on it. 
Statement: you can not use pure CSS and not use media queries, and still have the resizing of images (dependent on screen size).  Is that true?

However, if using javascript and css with the calc function, you can get away from using media queries?

Answer (score 2):

**RESULT**

[image]

---

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="squares">
    <div class="square">1</div>
    <div class="square">2</div>
    <div class="square">3</div>
    <div class="square">4</div>
    <div class="square">5</div>
    <div class="square">6</div>
    <div class="square">7</div>
    <div class="square">8</div>
    <div class="square">9</div>
    <div class="square">10</div>    
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: lightblue;
}

.container {  
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;

  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.squares {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 330px;
}

.square {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;

  margin: 5px;
  background: cyan;
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px #536a72;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .squares {
    width: 440px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 700px) {
  .squares {
    width: 550px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1050px) {
  .squares {
    width: 1050px;
  }

  .square {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much.  Yours handles the requirements very well!! question:  Isn't there a way to handle the smaller images besides media query, with a calculation?  As in this:

as the screen size is smaller, then reduce image size by the calculated value to the minimum image size. AFTER min image size has been reached, Now, start to wrap the image to the next row.

So resizing smaller image before start wrapping? IMO, that makes a smoother, more accurate resizing of images and not dependent on media?

at least, that is what I think is possible, but I wasn't able to do it

Comment: so I should be able to use the above examples and tweak yours :)

Comment: no problem, this should be a starting point of what you want to do it anyway you could see the other answers on how they're using calc() function or probably use Javascript.

Comment: do you know if there is another way to accomplish this without using the "squares" div?  Reason why, a lightbox i'm using breaks due to that extra div used.
As in:
<div id="LightBox" class="container">
    <div class="squares">
   <a href="#" >
      <img class="square" src="#" />
  </a>

---------
with  <div class="squares">, the lightbox breaks.
without it, the layout breaks. I'm trying to make them work together?

Comment: add to .squares selector this: `margin: 0 auto;` and remove div container from html

Comment: :)  thanks... when it comes to "tweaking" this type of css, know all the available options and testing in realtime, do you just KNOW this stuff by heart, or is there a tool that helps? becoming efficient at css, well you need lots of practice or the right tool? Both? Neither? Something else?  thanks for your help

Comment: learn and practice that's all you need to be proficient I'm still learning CSS by the way, and hey don't forget to accept the answer if you think it answered your question, have a great day !

Answer (score 0):

> Resize your screen

```css
.container {
  padding: 30px;
  background: #d2d2d2;
}

.container h4 {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.container .gallery {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container .gallery .item {
  width: 100vw;
  margin: 5px;
  height: 100vw;
  background: #fff;
  max-width: calc(100vw/5 - 30px);
  max-height: calc(100vw/5 - 30px);
  filter: drop-shadow(5px 7px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3));
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px){
  .container .gallery .item {
    max-width: calc(100vw/3 - 41px);
    max-height: calc(100vw/3 - 41px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h4>Div Container</h4>
  <div class="gallery">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. hope it help you.

```css
 

        body{
      background-color:rgba(191, 239, 255, 0.7);
     }
     .all-div{
      display: flex;
      -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      margin-right: -15px;
      margin-left: -15px;
     }
     .single-div{
      width: calc(100% / 5 - 10px);
      height: 150px;
      background-color: #b4f0ff;
      box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px #536a72;
      margin: 5px;
     }
     @media (max-width: 575px){
      .single-div{
       width: calc(100% / 3 - 8px);
       height: 90px;
       margin: 4px;
      }
      .container {
       padding-right: 30px;
       padding-left: 30px;
      }
     }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="all-div">
      <div class="single-div"></div>
      <div class="single-div"></div>
      <div class="single-div"></div>
      <div class="single-div"></div>
      <div class="single-div"></div>
      <div class="single-div"></div>
      <div class="single-div"></div>
      <div class="single-div"></div>
      <div class="single-div"></div>
       <div class="single-div"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```